# Fetch date where date time greater than current date time

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am working with php and mysql,Right now i have following table name "info"

```
id         name            end_date        end_time
1          abc             2023-02-03      02:02 PM
2          xyz             2023-02-04      10:10 PM 
3          axy             2023-02-01      11:12 PM
```

now i want to get all records where "datetime"(`end_date` + `end_time`) is less than "current time". In other words, my expected output is  "1st and 3rd record"

How can i do this  ?

Comment: why have you two columns for dataetime?

Comment: What have you tried? Why not store a datetime instead of two different columns?

Comment: Probably `concat` can be used and `cast` but would be best off just storing the data correctly to start with. `where cast(concat(end_date, ' ', concat(substr(end_time, 1, 5), ':00')) as datetime) <= now()`... oh, you'll need to convert `am`/`pm` to 24 hours as well. Really answer is to store data in proper format.